# PHP PDO fetchAll into class and constructor

Tags: php, oop, constructor, pdo

I'm trying to find the best way to use a class to turn data into a class but using the same class to insert into a table or return information and I'm not sure the best way to do that. The constructor seems to be giving me trouble conceptually. Right now I have a page that queries all the records into a class using:

`$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Contact", array($dbh))`

And of course that places each record into a "Contact" class placing each row into private data members of the same name and a database connection handle for add/update/delete records. That works perfectly fine. But turning raw data into a class gives me trouble. Following the syntax of the above code [to my knowledge] I can't have any other constructor parameters or it would be a sloppy hack. Here's the code I have:

```
class Contact {
    private $dbh;
    private $Contact_ID;
    private $Contact_First_Name;
    private $Contact_Last_Name;
    private $Contact_Email;
    private $Contact_Phone_Number;

    public function __construct($dbh) {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }

    // .. 
}
```

So if I try to create a new Contact object with data from a form, there's no way to store the data members. I tried a hack to get it to work having default parameters and checks for the default value to not change (as it is part of the fetchAll()) or if it isn't then store the new value but that didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: you code will end up violating [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: I don't think so, it all consists of Contacts records displaying the data of a contact or adding it into a contact. Is that too broad?

Comment: Why exactly the constructor of `Contacts` requires `$dbh` ?

Comment: Because it is needed for the add/update/delete record methods and that's the easiest way to store it for other methods.

Comment: Hence, the violation of SRP.

Comment: Okay thanks. So just insert records using accessors and manipulate the data through the Contact class for displaying records?

Comment: are you trying to make a ORM lib? there are existing solutions

Comment: @user1892641 , you might want to look into the [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern.

Comment: What if you store the values in a base class and then make derived classes for 'store_by_db' and 'store_by_form'? This way you could have specific constructors for each type of data.

Comment: @teresko That looks to be the best solution. I was hoping to rope all those into one having a base class with an abstract add/update/delete methods that are inherited, but I guess that won't work.

Comment: well .. you can, but you shouldn't. Basically you should separate the business logic from storage logic. It would result in `Contact` becoming a [domain object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject), which is not aware of storage, and having a different class handling all the storage interaction. Keep in min that "storage" is not just SQL database. It also can be cache, session, cookies, nosql, json/xml files or anything else that you can come up with. The `Contact` instance should not care about where and when it gets stored.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Thinking about it, it makes sense now.

Comment: Following that data mapper object example, should the mapper have a collection of contact objects as a data member then manipulate that between the database or have it be completely independent of both the database object and contact objects?